# Python lxml: How to tell if an element has been removed from a tree?

Tags: python, lxml

I am attempting to manipulate a DOM tree using `lxml`'s `etree` module.  One task I haven't figured out yet is how to test whether a particular node is still part of a parsed tree.  Since the behavior of `etree` is mostly undefined if you remove nodes during `_ElementTree.iter()`, I do the manipulation in two phases.

First, I iterate through the parsed tree and mark some nodes for removal and certain other nodes for further processing by placing them in respective lists.  The second phase consists of iterating through the list of nodes to remove and removing them from the tree.  At this point, I have a list of nodes to process further and a tree that has been pruned substantially since it was first parsed.

What I lack is a way to test if a particular node in my nodes-to-process list still lives in the parse tree.  If it isn't part of the tree, that means it's a descendant of one of the nodes I removed earlier and I want to discard it.  The problem is that there isn't an obvious way to do this test cheaply.  Even after a node has been removed from the `_ElementTree` calling `getroottree()` on that node returns the original tree.

I could call `iterancestors()` on each node-to-process and check for the root element I would expect for an in-tree node, but this is O(n) and won't scale well for deep DOM trees.

Does anyone know of a constant time operation, given an `Element` and an `_ElementTree`, to test whether the former is part of the latter?

I realize that traversing a node's parent chain upward might be the only way to do this test, and any faster way would require some bookkeeping to be implemented by the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 0: parse the xml into a tree.
Step 1: iterate over the tree, deleting nodes that need to be deleted.
Step 2: iterate over the remaining nodes, processing those that need it.

If you own step 0, you can use iterparse() with end events to save building a large tree only to remove many nodes later, and making step 1 much simpler:

```
for event, elem in etree.iterparse(input_xml):
    if elem needs deleting:
        elem.clear() # remove text, tail, attributes, and descendant elements
        delete_todo.append(elem)
```

Comment: what do you do with the "delete_todo" list? it seems there's another step in removing the actual node?

Comment: @Ramy: No "seems"; definitely true. Read the iterparse section of the docs -- while you are building the parse tree, you can't delete nodes that the parser is still using, like the current node. How: `for elem in delete_todo: elem.getparent().remove(elem)`  ... may need to trap "already removed" exceptions depending on how smart your "needs deleting" code is.